# How can I disable spring cloud stream binder kafka from a jhipster generate project?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jhipster, spring-cloud-stream

I'm setting up a project generated with jhipster and I want to disable the kafka stream cloud config from this project.
I didn't remember when I chose this configuration.
I can't launch my backend application because of this.

This is for a webapp with Angular and Java.

```
ERROR org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService - Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: provisioning exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:259) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: If you don't want the functionality of the kafka binder, why are you including them? If you remove the binder, this error will go away.

Comment: Jep, simply remove `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` from the dependencies in your maven/gradle file and you're good to go!

Comment: @TYsewyn nope I can't just remove ```spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka``` from the dependencies. 
I have an error ```ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed```
If you have an other solution or someone else !!!

Comment: If you don’t need Spring Cloud Stream, remove it altogether?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. ```Application run failed``` each time.

Comment: Can you please add some more information as to why you get "application run failed"? Without that it's fairly hard to help you out.
Also make sure you don't have any kafka dependencies in your maven/gradle file.

Comment: @TYsewyn thx for your help, I founded the last dependency which cause me trouble. 
I can launch my application now !